# wpdb-> not adding prefix to custom table

Tags: wpdb

I know it should work with custom table and I think it worked in previous development I believe. But this time I don't know whey it is not getting custom table with `$wpdb->tablename`

Code:

```
global $wpdb;    
$items = $wpdb->get_var($wpdb->prepare("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM $wpdb->review_media"));
```

This is not giving any result but when I tried with `$wpdb->prefix than it works

```
$wpdb->get_var($wpdb->prepare("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM ".$wpdb->prefix."review_media"));
```

Any idea

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`$wpdb->tablename` works only with the tables initially present in a WordPress installation. These tables are defined in `wp-includes/wp-db.php`.

The second method you used is perfectly acceptable.

Comment: Oh I see. I thought `$wpdb->` will add prefix with custom table as well. Thanks to clarify this was new to me.

Comment: @pixelngrain, you can add your table name like that. It does work. I tried it, but I don't know if it will get you trouble later on.

Comment: Yeh that is why I want to use prfix dynamically as I am developing plugin and prefix can be changed, depending on the installation. Thanks a lot again and using my second method.

Answer (score 10):

You are supposed to store the table name in $wpdb before you can use it the way you did.

```
$wpdb->review_media = "{$wpdb->prefix}review_media";
```

Comment: Do I need to replace `$tableprefix` with my prefix? or that is the class variable? Because I have added this before use but still happens nothing.

Comment: Yes, you would need to fill this variable yourself. But you can get the prefix out of $wpdb->prefix.

Comment: Thank's for editing kaiser. Should have been that simple in the first place. :-)